# Android Apk crashes after signed built - Proguard already turned off

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, proguard, signing

Android APK crashes after building a signed version, however debug version runs just fine when I deploy. I've checked the previous questions and tried disabling proguard but it's the same and the apk is still crashing.

Here's a output from my logcat

```
11-27 13:33:00.432 1130-1275/? E/cm_cmc_c: app launch:com.earnso.mangaworld
11-27 13:33:00.534 26412-26412/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl', referenced from method com.earnso.mangaworld.util.RarContentProvider.<clinit>
11-27 13:33:00.547 26412-26412/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.earnso.mangaworld, PID: 26412
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.jvm.internal.PropertyReference1Impl
                                                       at com.earnso.mangaworld.util.RarContentProvider.<clinit>(RarContentProvider.kt)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5037)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my gradle file

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-${getCommitCount()}"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            //multiDexEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        standard {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "INCLUDE_UPDATER", "true"
            dimension "default"
        }
        fdroid {
            dimension "default"
        }
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 19
            resConfigs "en", "xxhdpi"
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
```

I've even tried commenting out everything in the proguard but it's still the same. Also I'm building standardrelease version for the app. And the Application is coded in `Kotlin`